# Display content of example.com/file.php on example.com

Tags: php

I have a Cpanel hosting where I would like to publish a very simple (just a few lines of text) page under the `www.example.com`. Therefore I created an `index.php` file and uploaded to the root directory of the domain. Now it works perfectly under the `www.example.com/index.php`, but my goal is to load it's content when I visit `www.example.com`.

How should it be done? I tried to add `<?php header("Location: http://www.example.com"); ?>` into the header of the file, however nothing happened. I assume the answer is something trivial, but I can't figure it out since I never worked with PHP.

Comment: `DirectoryIndex` via `.htaccess` ?

Comment: @mario I added `DirectoryIndex index.php` into the `.htaccess`, but doesn't work.

Comment: Have you called the file `.html` or `.php`? you mention both.

Comment: What do you want to do? get the contents of index.html and display it in index.php? redirect to index.html? not sure what you are trying to do here     <?php header("Location: index.html"); ?> would redirect to index.html if you wanted to display something from a php file <?php echo 'Hello World!'; ?> would do the trick.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone my mistake, it's `.php`, `.html` was a mistake. It's `index.php`

Comment: Ok, check you have not got a file called .html in the web root too, if so delete it, open up just `www.example.com` in your browser, you will get an error if `DirectoryIndex index.php` is not present, if you dont then right click and view the source if its not parsing the PHP then thats your issue, that PHP needs to be enabled. Please tell us any errors your getting.

Comment: But why are you redirecting to example.com if index.php is your DirectoryIndex you will just be in a forever redirecting loop remove the header("location .. code and add <?php echo "hello world"; ?> go to example.com and tell me the output..

Comment: "nothing happened" and "doesn't work" are barely observations. See the access and error logs. Empty pages indicate looking at view source / and or debugging with `wget`/`curl` at the very least.

Comment: I contacted the support who fixed it for me. The guy told me that something was wrongly added to the .htaccess. Thanks guys for your efforts!